# Very confused. Seem to have lost my private key?

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, private-key

I created an Etherwallet today and printed out a hard copy. I also physically wrote down both my address and private key for security purposes. I carelessly transferred coins from Etherdelta to the address I had written down. I now notice that it was NOT the address attached to my private key. I don't know where the private key is to this address, but the money is sitting there.

Any ideas on desperate recovery moves here?

Comment: For anyone else reading this: please don't _manually_ write down any type of address or key (i.e. using a pen and paper). You're risking transcription errors. Copy and paste to a throw-away text file, and then print. (Manually writing down 12/24 word mnemonics are different because they're words which have a specific spelling.)

Comment: Not a lot you can do about that. If you had the private key of the address you ACTUALLY sent the coins to, you could just transfer them to the correct address. I hope it wasn't a large amount.